# Why is test deployment not working while normal deployment is OK

Tags: google-apps-script, web-applications, client-server, http-status-code-401

I have an GAS API that works fine with normal deployment.
(currently it just adds a timestamp to a spreadsheet for testing purpose).
But when I use the test deployment URL (incl. the ..../dev) it runs into 401 or 403.
The normal deployment is the very latest version, so the test deployment is same as normal live version.

What could be the cause of that?

I'm pretty novice/layman in this API and authorization domain.

appscript.json:

```json
{
  "timeZone": "Europe/Brussels",
  "dependencies": {},
  "exceptionLogging": "STACKDRIVER",
  "runtimeVersion": "V8",
  "webapp": {
    "executeAs": "USER_DEPLOYING",
    "access": "ANYONE_ANONYMOUS"
  }
}
```

Comment: Or am I completely misunderstanding the test deployment concept?? (not sure why somebody voted down my request. I have no clue how to take next step into this).

Comment: Test deployment is only accessible to the user who deployed. If you aren't sending necessary access headers or cookies, you'll run into 401(which you probably shouldn't send anyway, if you're  accessing it externally).

Comment: @TheMaster Thanks. So I assume I could add a access key in header. Not sure if/how it is possible to create that in GAS? (For now I wouldn't care that much. It is really not an imporant/interesting thing I am doing).But in general your advise is not to include that. I assume for security reasons: I have very very limited knowledge of that, but assume that an access key could be 'sniffed' if added to header or some other hacker methods. (using Post method doesn't make it better??). Better to us OAuth integration? (No clue how that works either. Would need to sort that out).

Comment: Why do you want to use a test deployment, when you can use a normal one? Test deployment is used mainly for actual web content/`doGet`, where you can view the webpage, when logged in the same google account(But, yes it is possible by sending  access tokens Tanaike  probably has a gist in github on it).

Comment: I am triggering the API from a flow in a backend system (MessageBird) that is invoked by a certain WhatsApp message that customer sends. (Customer replies a number of weeks it wants to postpone an order (via a WhatsApp button with that value). Then the API needs to process it in Google sheets. So as I am developing the API, I am testing it step by step. Would be easy if I can use the dev. But looks like 'easier'  way is to temporarily set it up as doGet and use a URL with parameters and use that in Chrome to invoke the API, rather than doPost with json.

Comment: Does that all sound logic in what I am doing? Or am I working in a complex way? (Just being an amateur programmer... enjoying the puzzling ;-)

Comment: I forgot, but I think you can deploy multiple times each with different urls - use one of them for testing. Regardless, if you must use `/dev` for testing, see https://github.com/tanaikech/taking-advantage-of-Web-Apps-with-google-apps-script?tab=readme-ov-file#how-to-use-dev-mode-from-outside

Comment: yes. I am now deploying with multiple different URLs, which is quite some clicks and copy/paste. Will check the github link. Thanks for your help!!!

Answer (score 0):

I build in a dual solution with both POST and GET. Seems to work fine. So I can easily use a URL with parameters in browser. (Wouldnt know how to do a post with parameters in an easy way other than using an application like in my case MessageBird. But that is probably due to my lack of programming experience).

````
  const params = e.parameter;
  let resp = apiPostponeOrCancelReOrdering(params);
  Logger.log(resp);
  return ContentService.createTextOutput(resp);
}

function doPost(e){

  var params = JSON.parse(e.postData.contents);
  let resp = apiPostponeOrCancelReOrdering(params);
  Logger.log(resp);
  return ContentService.createTextOutput(resp);
}

function apiPostponeOrCancelReOrdering(params){xxx}```
````